# simulating realtime data streaming Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation

I want to write a simulator that will mimic reading data from sensors(serial comm) except that it will be reading them from a file that was previously saved.I know that if I used the load function it will read the whole file, so I thought of using a loop that will scan the vector of the loaded file with a certain frequency. Now this will be very fast and it won't look like real time reading. How do I make it read the loaded file with a slower (maybe fixed)frequency so as to make it look like it's real time streaming and processing the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should load the whole file and then pull out frames and perform calculations on these frames.

Something like:

```
load('sensordata');

framelength = 1024; % Datapoints
Fs = 48000; % 48kHz
frame_duration = 0.01;
frame_length = frame_duration*Fs;
N = length(sensordata);
num_frames = floor(N/frame_length);


for i = 1:num_frames
  frame = sensordata((i-1)*frame_length+1:frame_length*i);
  %% Do actions here

end
```

Here's a video explaining it perfectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpXtsRpaLOA&t=944s

Comment: I already tried what you suggested, but when I plot the data it's very fast and doesn't resemble realtime plotting. This is because the loop will run very fast and execute the code, I tried using pause but I think the minimum pause is 0.001. I'm still experimenting on it, I hope it works. Thanks very much

Comment: Do you have access to the Audio System Toolbox in Matlab? It is made particularly for real-time processing where the function "step()" lets you read data in and out according to your sampling frequency i.e. making it possible to go exactly real-time if your algorithm processing time allows it of course.

Comment: matiastifteby No I don't have it, but I'm sure a trial can be found from Mathworks.com. Thank you very much!